# "create" action in child class results in "The action 'create' could not be found" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model `Membership` and a model `Student` that inherits from `Membership`

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Student < Membership
end
```

I have a form in `students/index.html.erb` to create a new Student:

```
<%= form_for(@student, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
```

I have a `create` action in `StudentsController`:

```
  def create
    # construct @student
    if @student.save
      redirect_to :back
    else 
      render 'index'
    end
  end
```

When I try to submit the form with invalid data, the submission fails gracefully, as expected. However, when I try to re-submit the form now, I get the error "The action 'create' could not be found for MembershipsController"

I'm curious why the resubmission is being routed to `'memberships#create'` (which does not exist) rather than `'students#create'`?

Comment: I have never seen this before :). Did you refresh the page before re-submit?

Comment: Please present the code from the StudentsController

Comment: No, it works fine if I refresh, but doesn't if I don't.

Comment: I added the code that declares the form and the code in the controller. I believe the issue is that it is applying the action associated with the parent class of @student.

Comment: Can you please show us the code where `@student` is being instantiated?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I just fixed it! The issue was that I was creating `@student` by accessing its parent. I was doing `@school.memberships.build()` and then setting the type of `@student` to "Student"